# Setting a string attribute of an active model including apostrophes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to set the value of an activerecord model as follows

```
New_Model.text_attr = "A selection of text including ' and " and other characters "
New_Model.save()
```

And I keep getting a mysql error for special characters. I've looked at other questions and I've seen how to do this as a raw sql query, but I'm not sure how to do this in an attribute oriented way. Can anyone give advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let it know that the " is being used as a part of the string. Insert a backslash before each of the special characters to treat them as a normal character i.e.

```
New_Model.text_attr = "A selection of text including ' and \" and other characters "
```

Comment: As far as I know you need to have it manually fixed before it can be assigned (before gsub can be called on it), otherwise ruby will just interpret the string having ended as soon as it hits the first closing quote.

Comment: If that solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't do it earlier.